# Cannot close and reopen Form in Access (OLE Connetion)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm a VBA noob but maybe you can help:

I want to refresh all Forms (subforms) and queries on my Main Form "FinalForm". However I use Access as a frontend to SQL server. So apparently the usual buttons (created with the wizard, like refreh, new record etc.) won't work.

I created a (stupid) workaround by closing and reopening the form:

```
Private Sub Befehl71_Click()
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "FinalForm"
    DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="FinalForm"
End Sub
```

This works fine within the vba editor but fails if triggered by button (something about an ole communication error).

How can I fix this ?

Comment: "something about an ole communication error" -- maybe the actual error msg might help.

Comment: I have truly no idead why but suddenly it worked: The code now is: Private Sub Befehl77_Click()

DoCmd.Close acForm, "FinalForm"

DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="FinalForm"

End Sub

Comment: Also sorry for this horribly disfigured thread...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard VBA procedure is

```
Me.Requery
```

For a subform only

```
Me.PUT_SUBFORM_NAME_HERE.Form.Requery
```

Comment: From OP: Same error: Communication error with OLE Server or ActiveX element...

However me.requery doesn't even work in the editor (compilation error, forbidden use of the keyword me)

Why is this so difficult...?

Comment: Try FormName.Requery where FormName is the name of the form

Comment: I tried that, still no success (same error). No success with your updated code either.

Comment: Me.WHATEVER can be used in the editor ONLY if it is in debug mode. Were you in debug mode when you tried it?

But I am happy for you it works now.

Comment: Thanks, btw. do you know why the standard button commands like "new record" won't work in an odbc/ sql scenario ?

Comment: Sorry I do not know. 
I have made a test with SQL Server 208 R2 and Access 2013, connected the tables via ODBC-wizard and built a form for the SQL tables. All the buttons like New, Save, Delete,.. are available and working. I suggest to create an extra question with details about your connection or to change your original question.